# My case 2 doesnt seem to be reading my .txt files in C programming

Tags: c, inventory

I've been working on this program for my job that I'm trying to make an inventory of tools. I'm very new to programming if there is an alternative rout to take on this I'm open to looking in to it.

My first case works. All it does is ask the user for a nomenclature, part number(P/N), and serial number (S/N).

The second case I'm trying to make it print the list of data.

My goal for this is to get my problem fixed for my second case

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main()
{
FILE * fp;
int qty;
int menu;
char nomen[26];
char pN[26];
char ans;
//Test to see if file exist
fp = fopen("Metro Inventory.txt", "w");
if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("*Error opening file*");
    fprintf(fp,"*Error opening file*");
    exit(1);
}
//Intro Header
fprintf(fp,"List of Special Tools:");
fprintf(fp,"\t\t\tPart Number:");
fprintf(fp,"\t\t Quantity:\n\n");

printf("Metro Aviation Tools List\n\n");
printf("What would you like to do?\n");
scanf("%d", &menu);
//loop of switch asking for nomenclature
do
{
    switch (menu)
    { //Case 1 adds new content
        case(1):
        {
        printf("Enter Nomenclature(no spaces):\n");
        scanf("%s", nomen);
        fputs(nomen, fp);
        fputs("\t\t\t",fp);

        //Part Number

        printf("What is the part number?\n");
        scanf("%s", pN);
        fputs(pN, fp);
        fputs("\t\t\t", fp);
        //Quantity
        printf("What is the quantity?\n");
        scanf("%d", &qty);
        fprintf(fp,"%d",qty);
        fputs("\n", fp);
        break;
        fclose(fp);
        }// Case 2 Edits content
        case(2):
        {

        int c;

                fp = fopen("Metro Inventory.txt", "r");
                if (fp) 
                    {
                    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
                        putchar(c);
                    fclose(fp);
                    }

            fclose(fp);
            break;
        }
        default : printf("Thank you");
        break;
    }//end switch
    printf("To add tool type Y.\n To exit type N.\n");
    getch();
    scanf("\n%c", &ans);
//loop
}
while ((ans == 'Y')||(ans == 'y'));
if ((ans == 'N')||(ans=='n'));
{
    exit(1);

}
```

getch();

return 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done file I/O for C for quite a long time however, a quick look into your program reveals that the time when you set/modify the value of menu is at line 26/27. Then, your loop starts at line 29. After that, there isn't any instruction to set/modify your menu value.

Later on at line 73 to 75, you are asking for input before the loop scope ends. This input is only used later on in another loop. What I'd suggest to you is to remove the whole switch case structure and allow the program to start away continue to do whatever you want to do. As there isn't any explanation too on why should the user pick 1 for menu or 2.

## Edit

It seems that you do not understand my initial comment, so I've taken the liberty to change some parts of your code.

Changes done:

1. Main() - For C programming, it has to have a type for the program entry point. Either void or int. Should you do `int main()` make sure to place `return 0;` before the last braces. Look at the modified code below for clarity.
2. Position of the code where the input for menu is supposed to happen. I placed it inside the loop so that the user will be prompt every time the loop restarts.

> In my initial answer or comment, I've said that in your original code, the point where you modify your variable required for the switch case to work only once and it happens before the loop.
>
> You must think from 1 line to another. What happens at line 1. How does line 1 affect line 2. In this example of yours, at line 26/27, you've set the value of menu to which ever input by the user (input validation is another topic). At that point, it is still linear, nothing loops so it means that your from the point you set the menu (line 26/27) to the point where the program exits (or ends) the value of menu remains static, unchanged.

3. `Removed exit(1);` I assumed you wanted the program to end if `fp` returns null and/or the user has chosen other input for `ans`. The issue of having an exit point is solved with the next modification I've made (refer to item 4).
4. Rearranged the code so that `if (fp != null)` which is the else part in the new code (refer to line 20) the program will allow the file to be written to. And should `fp` returns null, the whole program will exit with a `return 0;`.

## Modified code

> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> #include<stdlib.h>
>
> int main()
> {
>     FILE * fp;
>     int qty;
>     int menu;
>     char nomen[26];
>     char pN[26];
>     char ans;
>     //Test to see if file exist
>     fp = fopen("Metro Inventory.txt", "w");
>     if (fp == NULL)
>     {
>         printf("*Error opening file*");
>         fprintf(fp,"*Error opening file*");
>
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         //Intro Header
>         fprintf(fp,"List of Special Tools:");
>         fprintf(fp,"\t\t\tPart Number:");
>         fprintf(fp,"\t\t Quantity:\n\n");
>
>         do
>         {
>             printf("Metro Aviation Tools List\n\n");
>             printf("What would you like to do?\n");
>             scanf("%d", &menu);
>             //loop of switch asking for nomenclature
>
>             switch (menu)
>             { //Case 1 adds new content
>                 case(1):
>                 {
>                     printf("Enter Nomenclature(no spaces):\n");
>                     scanf("%s", nomen);
>                     fputs(nomen, fp);
>                     fputs("\t\t\t",fp);
>
>                     //Part Number
>
>                     printf("What is the part number?\n");
>                     scanf("%s", pN);
>                     fputs(pN, fp);
>                     fputs("\t\t\t", fp);
>                     //Quantity
>                     printf("What is the quantity?\n");
>                     scanf("%d", &qty);
>                     fprintf(fp,"%d",qty);
>                     fputs("\n", fp);
>                     break;
>                     fclose(fp);
>                 }
>                 // Case 2 Edits content
>                 case(2):
>                 {
>                     int c;
>
>                     fp = fopen("Metro Inventory.txt", "r");
>
>                     if (fp)
>                     {
>                         while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
>                             putchar(c);
>
>                         fclose(fp);
>                     }
>                     fclose(fp);
>                     break;
>                 }
>
>                 default :
>                     printf("Thank you");
>                     break;
>             }//end switch
>             printf("To add tool type Y.\n To exit type N.\n");
>             getch();
>             scanf("\n%c", &ans);
>
>         //loop
>         }while ((ans == 'Y')||(ans == 'y'));
>     }
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: Also switch line 51 to line 52 as the break at line 51 will not let you close the file which is at line 52

Comment: I did this so far. I changed switch to if statements I can take info in but still cant print them on my screen.

Comment: // Case 2 Edits content
    if (menu == 2)
    {
        int c;

            fp = fopen("Metro Inventory2.txt", "r");
            if (fp)
            {
                while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
                            putchar(c);
            }

    }

Comment: '    // Case 2 Edits content
    if (menu == 2)
    {
        int c;

            fp = fopen("Metro Inventory2.txt", "r");
            if (fp)
            {
                while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
                            putchar(c);
            }

    }
'

Comment: sorry idk how to upload code in the comment still very new to this site

Comment: Thank you for your time, I got it now. You where a lot of help!

Comment: No prob, if this is the answer you are looking for, you can mark it as one by clicking on the tick symbol to the top left of my post

Comment: Being new my vote is recorded in your rep. but wont be shown unfortunately.